# Calculate the number of common features an agent shares with an agentset

Tags: netlogo

I would like to report a count of the number of common features (e.g. [1 8 4] is three features) an agent (target_turtle) shares with each agent in an agentset (neighbor_turtle). Any suggestions please?

For example: If the agent has the features [1 8 7] and an agent from the agent set has the features [1 7 8], they share one common feature i.e. 1 . The features 8 and 7 are not included as the order of the features is relevant.

The current error I get is: All the list arguments to FOREACH must be the same length.

Cheers,
Marshall

```
;; reporting overlap between two agents

to-report overlap_between [target_turtle neighbor_turtle]
  let suma 0
  ask neighbor_turtle 
  [
  (foreach [feature] of target_turtle [Feature] of neighbor_turtle
    [ if ?1 = ?2 [ set suma suma + 1]  ]
    )
  report suma
  ]
end
```

Comment: So you've updated this to specify that order matters, but now I'm completely confused what problem you're trying to solve. Is `[1 8 7]` a feature, or is it three features? And in your example with `[1 8 7]`, did you mean to say something else the second time? In what you've written, the two agents have the same list, so surely you mean they have 3 features in common, not one. I would like to help, but you will need to specify, in detail and unambiguously, what it is that you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yes my bad. I made the correction. I meant [1 8 7] and [1 7 8] have only one common feature i.e. 1

Comment: Could you please demonstrate the procedure with a nested foreach loop if possible. Thnx

Comment: If order matters, you don't need nested foreach. You actually want to iterate over both lists in tandem. I only suggested nested foreach before, when you hadn't yet specified that order matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems almost correct already, though the `ask neighbor_turtle` part isn't necessary; you're already using `of` to switch perspectives.

The error message you're getting seems to indicate that you need to somehow handle the case where the turtle's feature lists aren't the same length.

I'll assume you just want to ignore any trailing items in the longer of the two lists. Here's code that does that:

```
to-report overlap-between [target-turtle neighbor-turtle]
  let features1 [feature] of target-turtle
  let features2 [feature] of neighbor-turtle
  ifelse length features1 > length features2
    [ set features1 sublist features1 0 length features2 ]
    [ if length features2 > length features1
      [ set features2 sublist features2 0 length features1 ] ]
  report sum (map [ifelse-value (?1 = ?2) [1] [0]]
                features1 features2)
end
```

Note that it's idiomatic in NetLogo to name variables `like-this` not `like_this`.

Comment: I intend to use mathematical operators on the output of the overlap-between function. What does the output look like when I call the overlap-between function? Is it possible to get a list which counts the overlap between a target-turtle and each neighbor-turtle

Comment: e.g. turtle 2 is the target-turtle with features [1 7 9]. The agentset includes turtle 0 and turtle 8 with features [1 8 2] and [0 7 4]. The list should look like [1 2] as it shares one feature with turtle 0 and two features with turtle 8.

Comment: This is a lot different than your original question; can you accept my answer, which I believe accurately answers what you asked? As for the new problem you've posed, why not try and code it yourself, and if you run into trouble, ask a new question, and show your new code?